# Question about commutator of groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This is an exercise from book *Algebra* by Thomas W. Hungerford, chapter 2.8, exercise 3.

If $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of a group $G$, let $(H,K)$ be the subgroup of $G$ generated by the elements $\{hkh^{-1}k^{-1} \mid h \in H,k \in K\}$. $G'$ is the commutator subgroup of $G$.

> Show that if $(H,G')=  \langle e\rangle$, then $(H',G)=  \langle e\rangle$.

This is how I tried:

since $(H,G')= \langle e\rangle$, $hah^{-1}a^{-1}=e$,which means every $h \in H$  commutes with $a \in G'$, and I don't know how to use this condition to prove $ h' \in H'$ commutes with $g \in G$.

Comment: Related http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/972457/commutator-of-a-group?s=2|1.1790

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $[g,h] = ghg^{-1}h^{-1}$.

Let $g \in G$, $h,k \in H$. We need to prove that $h^{-1}k^{-1}hk$ commutes with $g$, which is equivalent to $[hk,g] = [kh,g]$.

Now
$$ hgh^{-1}g^{-1}kgk^{-1}g^{-1} = hgh^{-1}(g^{-1}kgk^{-1})g^{-1} = hg(g^{-1}kgk^{-1})h^{-1}g^{-1} = [hk,g]$$
but also
$$ hgh^{-1}g^{-1}kgk^{-1}g^{-1} = (hgh^{-1}g^{-1})kgk^{-1}g^{-1} = k(hgh^{-1}g^{-1})gk^{-1}g^{-1}= [kh,g].$$