# N contains the commutator subgroup if and only if G/N is abelian, proof by words?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, free-groups

Working on some problems after my first semester of abstract-algebra. I saw this question

> $\mathbf{Theorem}$ Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of a group $G$. Then $N$ contains the commutator subgroup if and only if $G/N$ is abelian.

And saw [this solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/972457/commutator-of-a-group) but wanted to try my hand at a "slick" proof using a fact that I overheard once (which tbh I might be misstating). Is there anything useful in this proof? Or should I stick to the traditional method?

> $\mathbf{Proof}$ Every group $G$ is isomorphic to the quotient group of
>   a free group. If a group is abelian it is isomorphic to the quotient
>   group of a free group modded out by its commutator subgroup. Therefore
>   $G/N$ is abelian if and only if $N$ contains an isomorphic copy of a
>   commutator subgroup as in it contains the commutator subgroup of $G$.

Comment: The link is not working.

Comment: For an homorphism $f:G\to H$ (here $H=G/N$) then the image of $G$ is abelian iff $\forall x,y\in G$, $f(x)f(y)=f(y)f(x)$ iff $f(xyx^{-1}y^{-1})=1$ iff $\ker(f)$ contains $[G,G]$ (where $[G,G]$ is the subgroup generated by the $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$, it remains to show it is normal in $G$)

Comment: @reuns the proof seems to assume that $[G,G]$ is in fact a subgroup and states that $N$ is a normal subgroup so I think your proof is spot on. Did I miss something ?